# Google doesn't show advertisements when sexual words are in the content

Tags: google-adsense, adult-content, google-adsense-policies

In a Spanish curious news site. AdSense seems to block ads inside any page which contains some sexual words. In fact, these pages are scientific articles or curious news, like `Bears also practice oral sex`, or `Created a lubricant that gives you orgasms during 15 minutes`. Of course, there are no explicit images in those pages.

Any idea of how could I avoid these situations?  Should my site avoid talking about sex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adsense policies are clear about sexual content, ads cannot be displayed next to such content. I guess they don't make a difference between porn and scientific sex conversations.

If I were you, I would stop doing it right now, or you might be banned from AdSense.

Comment: All right, thank you. It doesn't have any sense for me, but Word of Google...

Answer (score 4):

From https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/4410771

> Google ads may not be placed on content that provides tips regarding sexual performance or discusses some treatments of sexual health issues. Examples include, but are not limited to:
>
> - advice about improving sexual performance
> - discussions and/or images of sexually transmitted diseases
> - sexual health advice related to pregnancy, childbirth, or family planning

I don't see it in the policies right now, but I believe that you can stay within their guidelines by not placing ads on the pages with prohibited content,  or on the pages that link to those page.   So you can still have AdSense on the rest of your site, just not where the Ads would appear within one click from adult content.

Google has put together a presentation about their [adult content policies for AdSense and you can watch it on Youtube](http://youtu.be/vJAyleW-R1E?t=4m34s).   The presentation is about half an hour long, but it goes into a lot of detail and really explains their policies.